# Cordova / Android Studio verions doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, gradle

When create a Cordova Android project by running *Cordova prepare* everything seems to be created correctly.
It creates a file called *cdv-gradle-config.json* with all versions that I want to use (the versions that are verfied from Cordova)
[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifQSh.png)

When I then open the project in Android Studio the build script and gradle seems to run fine. But Android Studio downloads Gradle wrapper 6.8 every time! Regardless of the version in the above file.

And when verifying all other versions for modules and dependencies in Android Studio they all seems to be unresolved:
[Modules versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O10I4.png)
[more issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLoKO.png)

And when looking into Gradle, it actually seems to be 6.8, but why is the version not fetched from the gradle config file created by Cordova?
[Gradle versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvM8X.png)

So my question is, why does it look like this? I have installed nodejs, Gradle and Cordova and they all work fine, except this behaviour.

I know I can just set the versions manually in Android Studio, but that's not the question, the question is why those dynamically versions from the config file doesn't work, and why Android Studio then "defaults" to 6.8 gradle. (I have 7.1.1 installed on my computer, which is verfied by *gradle  --version*

Software used:
Windows 10
Cordova CLI 11
Android Studio 2020.3.1
Gradle 7.1.1 (installed on my machine.)
Gradle wrapper 6.8 (used by Android Studio, why is this??)

Comment: Update your android studio to latest stable build and yes you have to set your Gradle version from Project Configurations screen for now if you are using cordova android@10.x.x

Comment: @stillKonfuzed I am using the latest Android Studio stable (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 patch4). There is no newer one.
According to Cordova they use Gradle 7.1.1... But is it correct that my projects get 6.8 by default?

Comment: If you are using build tools 32.x.x then your default gradle version will be 7.1.x , if you are targetting android-29 then gradle should be in 6.x.x range. I have just build 2 projects for android 12 till now so, I am not sure.